# Transacciones con PDO y Singleton

Tags: php, mysql, poo, pdo

Tengo el patrón `singleton` y una clase `ticket`:

```
public function registrar(){
//me conecto a la bd
$conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion(); 
 try{

  $conexion->beginTransaction();
  $queryid="select comprobante from identificadores;"; 
  $array=$conexion->query($queryid);
 foreach($array as $a){
   $id = $a['comprobante'];
  }

  $qnuevoid="UPDATE identificadores SET comprobante=".++$id.";";
  $conexion->query($qnuevoid);

    $queryticket="insert into despensa.ticket (idticket, fecha, total,vuelto) 
    values (".$id.",'".$this->fecha."',56,88);";
    $conexion->query($queryticket);

   $conexion->commit();
  }catch(Exception $e){
  $conexion->rollBack();
   echo "Fallo: " . $e->getMessage(); 
  }
  }
}
```

El caso es que quiero saber como acceder al valor de una consulta select mysql con PDO para evitar esto:

```
foreach($array as $a){
   $id = $a['comprobante'];
}
```

Me parece no es la forma correcta!

Comment: Tal y como está su consulta y su `foreach` , la asignación de valores en el caso que la consulta retornará más de 1 registro, el valor de `$id` sería solo el del último de estos. Y no creo que sea lo que está buscando.

Comment: El ultimo comprobante es un solo valor, osea el nuevo id de un ticket siempre es un solo valor, gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente en tu método  `singleton_conexion` no has proporcionado la opción **fetch_style** en este caso la llamada devolverá la opción predeterminado `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` que es un matriz indexado tanto por nombre de columna.
En el caso que tengo entendido se quieres que la llamada devuelve un objeto anónimo con nombres de propiedades que se corresponden a los nombres de las columnas tendrás que proporcionar como opción `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

Ex:

```
function singleton_conexion()
{
    // asigna opciones para la conexion PDO. en este caso asignamos el modo fetch al objeto,
    // "objeto", esto significa el resultado sera objeto en vez de array, como: $result->comprobante !
    // en caso contario, el modo  FETCH_ASSOC o sin especificar el modo devolvera: $result["comprobante] !
    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    $this->db = new PDO(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
}
```

[Aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) tienes mas ejemplos.